# Dagger does not initialize Lazy<T> lazy Variable?

Tags: java, inject, dagger, dagger-2

I am using Java and [Dagger](http://google.github.io/dagger/) dependency injection framework. Often I have situations where I have to init a class but used later e.g.:

```
private final Message message;

public SomePresenter() {
  message = DaggerComponent.getMessage();
}

public someFuncA() {
  message.doSomething();
}

public someFuncB() {
  message.doSomething();
}
```

I want that message is initialized the first time it is requested and from that moment alway use the same message instance in this class. How can I do that?

**Edit:**

I tried to use [Lazy](https://square.github.io/dagger/javadoc/dagger/Lazy.html) as follows but lazyMessage is `undefined`:

```
public class StartPresenter {

  @Inject
  Lazy<Message> lazyMessage; 

  @Inject
  public StartPresenter(ConfigObject config) {
  }

}
```

Here is my dagger2 configuration:

```
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface ApplicationComponent {

   Message getMessage();
}

@Module()
public class CoreModule {

  @Provides @Singleton
  Message provideMessage() {
    return new MessageImpl();
  }  
}
```

**How do I get lazyMessage being instantiated by dagger?**

Comment: access the `message` only via getter where you will initialize it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Lazy class like

```
@Inject Lazy<Message> message;
```

In your code use:

```
//Doing something with message
message.get().messageMethod();
```

[Here's the documentation for `Lazy`](https://square.github.io/dagger/javadoc/dagger/Lazy.html)

Dagger will only wire up the class when get() is called. It will return the same instance everytime get() is called.

Comment: How do you create an instance of StartPresenter?

Comment: Can we use Lazy in constructor injection in dagger?